# Обособление деепричастных конструкций с повторяющимся союзом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, деепричастный-оборот

Как обособляются деепричастные конструкции, соединенные повторяющимся союзом?
Ответьте, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые, взятые скобки?

***Тимофей следовал за ним (,) то прихрамывая, то идя быстрым ходом (,) и думал о своем.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаю, что обе запятые, указанные Вами, необходимы [на общих основаниях](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/151-zap-19-32). Первая запятая отделяет деепричастие, вторая — закрывает деепричастный оборот.

**Тимофей следовал за ним, то прихрамывая, то идя быстрым ходом, и думал о своем.**

> На тонком лезвии ножа,
>   **То падая, то спотыкаясь,**
>   Идти пытается душа,
>   Своим безумством наслаждаясь.

Думаю, Вы имели в виду особенности пунктуации при союзе «то... то», когда запятая ставится только перед второй частью союза. В Вашем случае это правило не работает.

[Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=329)

Вот интересное предложение, подтверждающее мои рассуждения.

*К гнездовью подобрался шакал и прыгал теперь на соли, **то** забегая вперед, **то** возвращаясь, подергивал **то** одной, **то** другой ногой, снова вел мордой, вставал на задние, чтобы передние перестало жечь, едва сдерживался, чтобы не заскулить, и оттого казалось, что он морщится* (А. Иличевский. Пловец).

Comment: Правило-то работает. На его основании ставится запятая между  частями. А ограничивающие запятые ставятся по другой причине. И упомянутого правила никак не отменяют.

Answer (score 1):

*Тимофей следовал за ним, **то прихрамывая, то идя быстрым ходом**, и думал о своем.*

В этом предложении обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастными оборотами, **обособляется,** как уже было сказано, **но объяснение я приведу немного другое.**

**Все мы читали Розенталя** и знаем, что деепричастные обороты могут обозначать или второе действие, или **признак** основного действия,  выраженного глаголом-сказуемым, что учитывается при обособлении. Также Розенталь предупреждает нас, что на решение влияют разные факторы, в том числе **структура** предложения.

С точки зрения семантики, деепричастия здесь обозначают именно **признак действия, а не второе действие.** Тимофей идет (следует) то прихрамывая, то быстрым шагом. Но не стоит забывать, что **любое обстоятельство может быть обособленным или необособленным**.

В данном случае это обособленное обстоятельство, имеющее **вставочный характер**. Почему? Дело в том, что основная мысль сообщения такова: ***Тимофей следовал за ним и думал о своем.***

Это же обстоятельство не будет обособляться, если логический центр высказывания переместится на характер движения, например:

*Его спутник хорошо знал дорогу и явно торопился, а Тимофей следовал за ним т**о прихрАмывая, то идя быстрым ходом.***

В этом случае ударение уже падает не на глагол, а на обстоятельство.

Comment: А у меня ударение падает на оборот, а не на "следовал". А у вас, получается, наоборот.

Comment: Ударение можно поставить где угодно, но надо понимать зачем. Важно видеть основную семантику и семантику второго плана. Здесь описана основная ситуация, выраженная однородными сказуемыми (шёл и думал о своем). А вы ставите в центр прихрамывающую походку персонажа. В каждом предложение есть композиция, как и в рисунке: что-то на первом плане, что-то на втором, одно - главное, другое - детали. А вы рисуете всё в одной плоскости, объемной картинки у вас нет. И вообще, для вас истина важнее или кто правильный ответ дал?

Comment: Важно, чтобы другие согласились или доказали, что я не прав. То есть истина. А вы согласились, что тут образ действия. Я-то опасался, что союз с двумя вариантами образа действия как-то на это всё-таки влияет. У меня ударение по аналогии со следующим: *Тимофей шёл бЫстро и думал о своЁм.* Образ действия тоже выступает в роли наречия, как и здесь. В предложении из вопроса ударение тоже падает на "своём", а не на второй глагол. Ваш вариант композиции я вижу (в конце ответа он был рассмотрен). Но я вижу "два варианта рисунка".

Comment: Вы рассматриваете одну грамматику, не учитывая ни структуру, ни лексическое наполнение предложения. Распространенное обстоятельство, выраженное двумя деепричастными оборотами,  скорее всего будет обособлено, так как оно некомпактное, явно выпадает из текста, растягивает интонационную фразу. Не подходит здесь линейная форма, обязательно нужны два плана. Это всё интонационно-структурные соображения. А еще есть семантика,  где желательно выделить основной план сказуемых и дополнительное описание характера движения.

Comment: А вы тоже как будто в конструктор играете. Изменяете предложения, так что от него мало что остается, да еще зачем-то ударения расставляете. Ударения в оригинальном тексте ставятся, в его окончательном варианте.  В общем нет, незачет вам (шутка). Единственное ваше достижение - это то, что вы правильно обозначили грамматическую функцию оборотов  как  обстоятельство, да и то не могли этим воспользоваться. Если вы рассчитываете на понимание, то анализ должен быть кратким, четким, строгим, с хорошей логикой. А если этого нет, то и читать никто не будет, не то чтобы понимать.

Comment: А расставлять ударения - это ваша фишка. У вас перенял этот принцип. У меня оно так: *Тимофей следовал за ним тАк-то и думал о своём.* А у вас так: *Тимофей следовал за ним, а именно так-то, и думал о своём.* Для меня первый вариант естественней.

Comment: А у меня получается 10 слов на одном дыхании. И тогда образ действия является центральным элементом смысла. Все ударения такие: *Тимофей следовал за ним то прихрАмывая, то идя быстрым хОдом и думал о своЕм.* Смысл такой: следовал вот тАк-то и думал о своём. Если убрать "за ним", то такие ударения становятся очевидными. Сравнить: *Тимофей следовал за ним прихрамывая и думал о своём.* Здесь тоже нужно обособить? Считаю, что размер тут не имеет значения.

Comment: Не рекомендуется 10 слов говорить на одном дыхании, это неудобно. И ваша линейная цепочка слов невыразительна с художественной точки зрения, не стала бы я читать такие книги. Но с точки зрения правил ваш вариант, как я думаю, возможен.

Comment: Вот. Это я и хотел от вас услышать)))

Comment: А что насчёт: *Тимофей следовал за ним прихрамывая и думал о своём.*? Если в центре смысла "следовал и думал", то обособляем так же, как и с большим оборотом? Правильно?

Comment: Тимофей слЕдовал за ним, прихрАмывая, и думал о своЁм.?

Comment: Ну вроде так получается. Но гораздо лучше звучит, если ударение на "ним" поставить. Просто мне кажется, что размер тут не влияет на обособление. Хотя при меньшем обороте обособление менее естественно. Или нет...

Answer (score 0):

Запятые **не нужны**, так как деепричастный оборот выражает образ действия:
*Следовал (каким образом?) то прихрамывая, то идя быстрым ходом и...*
Более того, логическое ударение падает на деепричастный оборот, а не на глагол "следовал".

Розенталь:
Деепричастный оборот не обособляется, если он (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113

Похожие примеры Розенталя:
*Старик шёл **прихрамывая на правую ногу**.* || Наше слово.
*Это упражнение делают **стоя на вытянутых носках**.

Студенты приобретают знания **не только слушая лекции, но и выполняя практические работы**.

В ту же минуту старая женщина вошла **припевая и подплясывая**.

Кучер мой слез **молча и не торопясь**.

Веретьев сидел **наклонившись** и похлопывал веткой по траве.*

---

В примере с другого вопроса "*прыгал, забегая/возвращаясь*" никак не является образом действия. Поэтому оборот и обособляется.

А вот с пунктуацией в стихе (с другого ответа) всё интереснее. Её можно объяснить следующим правилом Розенталя:
Обособление или необособление деепричастного оборота может зависеть от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому: одно и то же слово в начале или в середине предложения может обособляться, а **в конце — нет**.

*Он говорил **запинаясь**.* || Позиция в конце.
*Он добавил, **запинаясь**, несколько слов от себя.* || Позиция в середине предложения перед глаголом.

*Они шли **не торопясь**.* || Позиция в конце.
*По дороге, **не торопясь**, они собирали грибы и ягоды.* || Позиция в середине предложения перед глаголом.

*Она будила сына **улыбаясь**.* || Позиция в конце.
***Улыбаясь***, она разбудила сына. || Позиция в начале предложения перед глаголом.

*Ужинали **не спеша**.* || Позиция в конце.
*Через двор, **не спеша**, шагал приземистый, коротконогий, круглоголовый человек.* || Позиция в середине предложения перед глаголом.

В стихе тоже позиция в середине предложения перед глаголом. Поэтому есть обособление.

---

Но постановка запятых ошибкой не будет — но это авторская (нестандартная) пунктуация. Тогда логическое ударение будет падать на слово "ним", а деепричастный оборот будет иметь характер уточнения. А смысл равносилен следующему:
*Тимофей следовал за нИм, то прихрамывал, то шёл быстрым ходом, и думал о своем.*

Comment: Вы неверно трактуете понятие образа действия. У нас оборот не является смысловым центром и не составляет единое целое со сказуемым.

Comment: Это ваше мнение. Вы это Розенталю объясните, у которого "шёл прихрамывая" - образ действия. Глагол особо роли не играет: или следовал, или бежал, или передвигался, или шагал. В конце вопроса рассмотрена другая трактовка, где оборот не связан со сказуемым.

Comment: Розенталь умер. Но при жизни он не нуждался в моих объяснениях. У меня всё. В пререкания с вами вступать более не намерен.

Comment: Я образно имел в виду. Как не понять-то?! У меня тоже всё.